# Drag elements when using scale in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to add drag behavior to elements (circles) in SVG which are plotted using a linear scale. I have also added zoom functionality to svg. But when I drag an element, depending on the zoom scale, the elements are moved farther. Could anyone please give me any pointers to fix this issue?

However, it is working fine when I render the elements directly without scale. I think it is something to do with correcting the x and y coordinates with respect to scale and zoom but not getting where to fix it.

Here is a sample [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavaa/80e67ta5/17/) which shows the issue -

```js
let data = [
      { x: 10, y :10},
      { x: 20, y :20},
      { x: 30, y :30},
      { x: 40, y :40},
      { x: 50, y :50},
      { x: 60, y :60},
      { x: 70, y :70},
      { x: 80, y :80}
    ];
    let width = 600, height = 300;

    let xDomain = d3.extent(data.map(d => d.x));
    let yDomain = d3.extent(data.map(d => d.y));
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).rangeRound([0, width]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).rangeRound([0, height]);

    let svg = d3.select("#map-container")
                                    .append("svg")
                                        .attr('height', height)
                      .attr('width', width)
                      .attr ("style", "outline: thin solid lightgray;");
    
    let g = svg.append("g");
    g.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
      .style('fill', 'blue')
      .call(d3.drag().on('drag', drag));

    function drag(event, d) {
      d3.select(this)
            .attr('cx', event.x)
          .attr('cy', event.y);
    }

svg.call(d3.zoom()
         .extent([[0,0], [width, height]])
         .scaleExtent([1,10])
         .on('zoom', zoom));

function zoom({ transform }) {
  g.attr("transform", transform);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-container"></div>
```

Though the drag event is getting correct coordinates of the mouse, the elements are not placed correctly.

Comment: Could you explain the issue in more detail with examples? I find the behavior in the provided code examples seem as expected. Ah I got it now, you are trying to drag single circles not pan the whole chart.

Comment: You are better off to use mouse events directly and set the circle position to the x and y mouse coordinates.